# Customize Javascript pop up window "title" in Chrome

Tags: visualforce, javascript

how can I remove the *"From an embedded page at..."* and replace it with a custom message. I am trying to display a pop up alert in the home tab to show users a reminder every time they log in(will only be using this alert for two days).

I created a Visualforce Page with nothing on it but the javascript alert. Then I added the VF Page to the Home Page Layout for the alert to display everytime a users navigates to HOme Page.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Sample Javascript Alert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the message; this is a security feature implemented in all modern browsers. This helps users to identify potentially malicious or fake messages.